# Using S-pen (Samsung stylus pen) to annotate books in Amazon Kindle App

Tags: samsung, amazon-kindle, s-pen, amazon-kindle-app

I have an Samsung Galaxy Note S22 Ultra and a Samsung Galaxy Tab S7 FE. My goal is to annotate E-books from Amazon with my S-Pen. Can I do that on these devices?

Unfortunately, I do not see any possibilities to do so in the official Amazon Kindle App.

Please help if you know how to do it. Are there any alternative apps that will let me annotate E-books?

Comment: Amazon Kindle does allow for highlighting sentences and also adding a "note", usually in text form. What about, taking a screenshot and then opening it in a paint app to draw over?

Comment: I would like to annotate mathematics books with my handwritten remarks, as a student, and also to fill in spaces in a language study textbook by hand, so taking screenshots and using an alternative viewer for the annotation is too time consuming and also for later documentation of study efforts rather impractical.

Comment: And another e-book reader won't work because the books are presumably purchased via Amazon?

Comment: @AP that is exactly the case.

Comment: There is a new kindle version called kindle scribe, but I would like to avoid purchasing another device, since I am a collector of antiques, not of modern electronic devices. Amazon may consider an obvious fix for their android kindle app.